# Defining a method visible only within a certain module/class

Tags: ruby, methods, visibility

Is there a way to define a method `foo` on module/class `A` so that it will be visible only from within module/class `B`, or its descendants? The following illustrates this situation:

```
A.new.foo # => undefined

class B
  A.new.foo # => defined
  def bar
    A.new.foo # => defined
  end
  def self.baz
    A.new.foo # => defined
  end
end

class C < B
  A.new.foo # => defined
  def bar
    A.new.foo # => defined
  end
  def self.baz
    A.new.foo # => defined
  end
end
```

I intuitively felt refinement was close in spirit, but it does not seem to do what I want.

Comment: What is the problem with refinements? As far as I understand them, you should be able to use A refinement within B and achieve exactly what you describe.

Comment: With refinements, you have to write `using ...` each time within the class body of `B`. That is impractical.

Answer (score -1):

This works. ^_^

```
class A
    private
    def foo
        "THE FOO !!!"
    end
end

class B < A
    public :foo

    def initialize
        @foo = self.foo
    end
end

puts "A.new.foo #{ A.new.foo rescue '... sorry, no.' }"
=> A.new.foo ... sorry, no.

puts "B.new.foo #{ B.new.foo rescue '... sorry, no.' }"
=> B.new.foo THE FOO !!!
```

If you want to use the A.new.foo within all sub classes by still using the A class name then you should use the following.

```
class A
    private
    def foo
        "THE FOO !!!"
    end
end

class B
    class A < A
        public :foo
    end

    attr_reader :c, :d

    def c
        A.new.foo
    end

    def d
        A.new.foo
    end
end

puts "A.new.foo #{ A.new.foo rescue '... sorry, no.' }"
=> A.new.foo ... sorry, no.

puts B.new.c
=> THE FOO !!!

puts B.new.d
=> THE FOO !!!
```